# SharePoint Web Parts and SharePoint Web Services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am looking at SharePoint web services and would like to know the best way to work with web parts.  I have figured out most of the other stuff we will need but the functionality around web parts and the SharePoint Web Services seems complicated. So how do I

1. Retrieive a particular web part with HTML content? Is this possible?
2. Find out what web parts are on what pages?

I know that I can get the rendered html for an entire page through web services (although why that is exactly useful when you can retrieve the web page directly I'm not sure.) but would like to know if it is possible to embed web parts in external web sites through SharePoint Web Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Web parts" are a means of "programming" Sharepoint.  They are to Sharepoint much like "controls" are to Visual Basic, or "views" are to Android.

   They're a creature of Sharepoint - I can't imagine you'd use them on an Apache server on a Linux host, for example.
2. Sharepoint web services, however, *are* intended to be a good way for Sharepoint to communicate with non-Microsoft technologies (like Java, for example).

If your "application" involves a heterogeneous mix of web servers and platforms, then Web Services is probably the way to go.

If your "application" resides exclusively on the Sharepoint server, and your "clients" just browse to it (preferably, browse to it with IE), then web parts might be a good choice.